# SCSS alias in Vue SFC via Rollup

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, rollup, rollupjs

When using Webpack is pretty straight forward to add an alias for scss files in a Vue SFC, e.g:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "~scss/config/config";
...
</style>
```

Would be the following in Webpack:

```
alias: {
  sass: path.resolve(__dirname, '../scss/')
}
```

How would you add the same kind of alias in Rollup via `rollup-plugin-vue`?

I've tried adding a number of postcss plugins, e.g

```
import importer from 'postcss-import';

vue({
    css: false,
    style: {
      postcssPlugins: [
        importer({
          path: null,
          addModulesDirectories: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared')]
        })
      ]
    }
  }),
```

I've also tried: `rollup-plugin-alias`, `rollup-plugin-includepaths` and some other postcss plugins.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No unfortunately not, I've had to keep the full paths in place. If I ever do figure it out I'll try and remember to come back here and update the answer.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I have a similar problem, and I find this area of the vue plugin undocumented for the most part. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can use `postcss` plugins within the Vue plugin to accomplish this, because it compiles the `scss` before it gets passed to `postcss`.
Using `rollup-vue-plugin` I've been able to use [`style.preprocessOptions.scss.includePaths`](https://rollup-plugin-vue.vuejs.org/options.html#style-preprocessoptions) to alias directories, in my case pointing to `node_modules`:

```js
//rollup.config.js
import VuePlugin from 'rollup-plugin-vue'
...
plugins: [
  VuePlugin({
    style: {
      preprocessOptions: {
        scss: {
          includePaths: ['node_modules'],
      }
    }
  })
]
...
```

```
// some .vue file
<style>
  @import 'some-node-module' //resolves to 'node_modules/some-node-module'
</style
```

Comment: Hi folks, any progress on this?